# StartupPath not taking 9 characters off in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, filepath

i am currently trying to redirect a path to save an image in a folder.

The Startup path is:

```
C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\bin\Debug
```

I am trying to change it so its like:

```
C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication
```

The code i am currently using is:

```
private void browseBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
                //open directory
                open.Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|ALL Files (*.*)|*.*";
                open.FilterIndex = 1;
                if(open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                   if(open.CheckFileExists)
                   {
                       string paths = Application.StartupPath.Substring(0, (Application.StartupPath.Length - 10));
                       System.IO.File.Copy(open.FileName, paths + "\\Images\\sss.jpg");
                   }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Any help or ideas on the matter? why isnt it taking off the characters so i can use images as the path

Comment: You realise this will only work for your project, not when deployed elsewhere?

Comment: Side Note: `CheckFileExists`: Gets or sets a value indicating whether the dialog box displays a warning if the user specifies a file name that does not exist.

Comment: @AlexK. I know this will only work for my project.

Comment: @DonaldBury and, do you know that when you build your `Release`, instead of `Debug`, it won't work too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code:

```
string source =
    @"C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\bin\Debug";

string path = source.Substring(0, source.Length - 10);
Console.WriteLine(path); 
//resulting in C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication
```

### ....If

:

1. You build the project as "Debug", not "Release"
2. The image directory and the `sss.jpg` image do exist.

But the way to get the path the way you do now is just... **unsafe** (at the very least). Try to use `Path.Combine` and `string.Split("\\")` instead:

```
string source = @"C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\bin\Debug";
string[] items = source.Split('\\');
string path = Path.Combine(string.Join("\\", items.Take(items.Length - 2)), "Images\\sss.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you actually want to cut 2 subdirectories off and then combine with `\Images\sss.jpg`:

```
  String source =
    @"C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\bin\Debug";

  String[] items = source.Split(new Char[] { 
    Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar });

  String path = String.Join(
    Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), items.Take(items.Length - 2));

  String result = Path.Combine(path, @"Images\sss.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code and should work just fine so long as the Images directory exists. Just use

```
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(path, "Images")))
      Directory.Create(Path.Combine(path, "Images")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason not to just leverage DirectoryInfo?  It looks like you just want to go up two directories. You should be able to use DirectoryInfo.Parent to get the path you need without needing to do string manipulation.

```
DirectoryInfo startupDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath);
DirectoryInfo twoDirectoriesUp = startupDirectory.Parent.Parent;
string fullDirectoryName = twoDirectoriesUp.FullName;
```